# Sorting values in a map

Tags: apex, map

I have a map as below :

```
caseMap = new Map<String,String>();

for(Case c: CaseList){

    if(!caseMap.containsKey(c.OwnerId)) {
        caseMap.put(c.OwnerId, c.Owner.Name);
    }                   
}
```

which I am using in VF Page :

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseMap}" var="userid">
    <option value="{!userid}">{!caseMap[userid]}</option> 
</apex:repeat>
```

I want the value part  to be sorted . Is it possible to sort within map? Or do I need to take the values in list ? Any code snippet would help.

Comment: best would be to use a wrapper class list and sort using [`Comparable Interface`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm)

Answer (score 5):

You will have to go through a list, there is no way to sort sets or maps, they are always unsorted. I would suggest to query the Owners them selves, sort them and walk through them. Sorting SObject lists uses the record names [as documented here.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sorting_sobject.htm)

```
public List<User> owners { get; set; }
owners = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id IN (SELECT OwnerId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :CaseList)];
owners.sort();
```

VF:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!owners}" var="user">
    <option value="{!user.Id}">{!user.Name}</option> 
</apex:repeat>
```

Hope this helps and works under your circumstances.